# Repeated functionality/code in Python classes, initializers and methods

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, initialization

I am trying to implement a repeated functionality in classes (including their initializers) and methods in an efficient and Pythonic way.

I am subclassing and overriding methods (as seen [here](http://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manipulating.html)). I have counters defined and augmented assignments on each class.

My code

```
class StructuralAnalysis(object):
    def __init__(self):
      self.counter_results = []  # probably a dict would be better

    def generate_structural_metrics(self):
        # declare counters
        cnum = 0
        cstr = 0
        cbytes = 0
        ...
        ...
        ...

        for node in ast.walk(self.tree):
            if isinstance(node, ast.Num):
                cnum += 1
            elif isinstance(node, ast.Str):
                cstr += 1
            elif isinstance(node, ast.Bytes):
                cbytes += 1
            elif ...
            elif ...
            elif ...

            self.counter_results = [cnum, cstr, cbytes, .......] 
            # some counters may require some further calculations

            return self.counter_results
```

My question is whether the above could be implemented in a more Pythonic and/or efficient way; like having a different class method for each counter that each overridden method will call to perform the augmented assign? This in order to avoid a -potentially- large amount of counter declarations and repeated code. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: are you looking for meta programming in python ?

Comment: @biobirdman no idea what that is. Just exploring 'best' approaches on implemented repeated functionality in classes really..

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a bunch of classes, since the overhead probably is too big (assuming most only keep a single counter, for that ast type).

However, I would check if there is a way to get the ast type via a function (so not a boolean for isinstance, but type(var). When you have the ast type you can use the dictionary you already had as idea to write something like

```
counters = {}
for node in ast.walk(self.tree):
    counters[type(node)] += 1
```

This will iterate through all nodes and add the counters into a dictionary.

For the additional calculations you can make another dictionary:

```
counter_calculations = {}

counter_calculations[ast.BYTE] = perform_additional_calculations_byte
```

For each type add the function reference if there is a function needed. This way you can call very easily the extra calculations needed for a type (you can use it in the same iterator).

```
if (type(node) in counter_calculations:
    counter_calculations[type(node)]()
```

Then implement the functions, for example for a byte:

```
def perform_additional_calculations_byte(byte_node):
     ... some calculations
```

For the counter results to return you can return the counters dictionary.

Comment: I struggle to understand what you suggest (newbie in Python). Could you please take a few minutes to implement what you are saying onto the small code chunk I put in my description as an example?

Comment: All your code I adapted into what I think is the solution you are looking for (or do I miss a code chunk?)

Comment: I understood what you suggest. Very clever. However, for this specific case I do need to have all the `isinstance` checks, so I guess this is not an ideal solution for me. I will accept your answer if no other suggestions are presented.

Comment: If you need the isinstance (because you want to 'group'  some classes as a type for example, you can make a different function who converts a class/type to an ast type you want to use and put that in the dictionary.